# What's the most common verb to use when you are undergoing medical exams?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I think you can say the following:

> I'm at the hospital, doing medical exams.
>
> I'm at the hospital, undergoing medical exams.
>
> I'm at the hospital, having medical exams.
>
> I'm at the hospital, taking medical exams.

I'm not very sure if some of them may be confused with taking a *written* medical exam (you can't discard the possibility that someone could be at the hospital *writing* a exam).

Which of them is less ambiguous? Is there a better choice?

Comment: I prefer your second option using *undergoing.* You could rewrite a little to rid the statement of all ambiguity and say something like, "I'm at the hospital, where my doctor is conducting medical tests on me."

Comment: Do you mean you’re getting/having some tests done?

Comment: @tchris Thanks for the suggestion. Didn't thought of that.

Comment: So *test* is more commonly used for medial examinations than *exam*?

Comment: I think test in general is more commonly used in the US than, say, in the UK or its former colonies.

Comment: Oddly, while *medical test* and *medical examination* could mean either 'checkup by a doctor' or 'what converts a medical student into a doctor', *medical exam* would usually mean the latter. (Actually, *medical tests* usually means the former, but I think that is because students usually take formal examinations rather than brief tests- for which patients are properly grateful.)

Comment: The most natural? On your cellphone, your mom calls, "Honey, where are you, you were supposed to pick me up an hour ago." "Sorry I didn't call, mom, I'm at the hospital having some tests done... what , no nothing's wrong at all, just ruling out some things. Sure, pot roast would be great. No, I'm not seeing her anymore, I told you she moved to Peru and we thought...no, I'm not going to give you her number... Yes... Yes... Yes... Yes... Yes... OK See you later." Your sentences are all too formal for natural speech; they might work for reporting formally.

Comment: I usually say I'm having medical adventures.

Comment: @KaiserOctavius@ though unsure about relative usage, I am certain the US is in fact a former colony.

Comment: @TimLymington: Er, yes, I knew that.

Comment: janoChen, you can use the word *the*, if you are talking about one hospital in particular and you have already established which one. Otherwise, it is contradictory. The usual wording in England and the rest of the UK, is *I'm in hospital*. You can follow that with *having tests*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the US, a very common way to express this concept is

> I'm at the hospital for tests.

No one would think you either are taking a non-medical exam or administering one.

Answer (score 2):

You could say

"I'm at the hospital having a **check-up**."

You can also replace "check-up" with **medical** or **physical** where it is implicit that you are referring to a an examination of your health and not a test of your medical knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

All of OP's alternatives are inappropriate for his intended meaning. Although **exam** is obviously short for **examination**, the short form is almost exclusively reserved for the *academic test* context.

But *doing* and *taking* are also far more associated with the "academic" context. The only credible alternatives are...

> 1: I'm at the hospital, undergoing medical examinations.
>    2: ?I'm at the hospital, having medical examinations.

But I personally don't much like #2. I'd probably say *having medical **tests*** there. Of course, there are many other more substantial rephrasings, such as..

> 3: I'm at the hospital, being medically examined.

Comment: To me, simply *undergoing examination* would not imply an academic exam.

Comment: @TrevorD: I don't understand why you've said that. I certainly haven't suggested it *would* - and in fact I've very strongly implied that it *wouldn't*. My #1 rephrasing simply substitutes *examination* because OP's abbreviation *exam* ***always*** means an academic test. It's the closest alternative with OP's intended meaning (his *medical condition* is being diagnosed). He could say he's having a *test, checkup, physical*, etc., but he's asking about *exams*. I'm just saying whatever else he does, most importantly he has to use *examinations*, not *exams*, for that sense.

Comment: FF It wasn't a criticism at all. It was merely intended as another suggestion. Sorry if it came over differently.

Comment: @TrevorD: oic. Perhaps I didn't express myself well. That's what I intended the second sentence in my answer to convey.

Comment: FF On reflection, I think maybe **I** didn't express myself well. I understood the second sentence of your answer to mean that. I was then suggesting (not very clearly!) that one could consequently  go one step further and omit the word "medical" from the example sentences entirely. I was trying to add another variation to your 3 examples by suggesting that simply saying, "I'm at the hospital, undergoing examination." would be sufficient.

Comment: @TrevorD: I quite agree - in the context of *hospitals* and *examinations*, the word *medical* is effectively redundant.

Answer (score 0):

In North America, there's also the *work-up*, meaning a *diagnostic investigation*.